# How To Display Single Image Thumbnail in product detail page Magento 2

Tags: magento2, thumbnail, gallery

I want to know how can I display `thumbnail image`, if the product has only one image . **(product detail page)**

Answer (score 1):

You just set checkbox true from admin,

```
 Catalog -> Product -> Edit Product
```

Now go to Image and video tab,
Click on Your image, popup will display,
[image]

SAVE PRODUCT.

Comment: hai thanks for your ans. Actually i want to know   'single image'  but show in thumbnail

Comment: Just disable/untick thumbnail from image from ROLE section in above popup.

Comment: hai Sry  , i want  to show 'single  image'  thumbnail

Comment: hai my question is edited @Rakesh

Answer (score 1):

fotorma.js:

```
if (size >1) {
                o_nav = opts.nav;
                o_navTop = opts.navposition === 'top';
                classes.remove.push(selectClass);

                $arrs.toggle(opts.arrows);
            } else {
                o_nav = false;
                $arrs.hide();
            }
```

> change (size > 1) To (size >= 1)

Answer (score 0):

Referring to kamal's answer, I made changes in the test server to debug and finally solved the problem.
My Magento version is 2.4.3.
First, rewrite the fotorma.js file, copy the file to

> app/design/[Vendor]/[Theme]/web/fotorama/fotorama.js.

Then find the code at line 2102.

```
 if (size > 1) {
    o_nav = opts.nav;
    o_navTop = opts.navposition === 'top';
    classes.remove.push(selectClass);

    $arrs.toggle(!!opts.arrows);
} else {
    o_nav = false;
    $arrs.hide();
}
```

Change this code to

```
if (size > 1) {
    o_nav = opts.nav;
    o_navTop = opts.navposition === 'top';
    classes.remove.push(selectClass);

    $arrs.toggle(!!opts.arrows);
} else if (size == 1) {
    o_nav = opts.nav = 'thumbs';
    opts.navdir = 'vertical';
    o_navTop = opts.navposition === 'top';
    classes.remove.push(selectClass);

    $arrs.toggle(!!opts.arrows);
} else {
    o_nav = false;
    $arrs.hide();
}
```

This way the thumbnails are displayed properly.

> opts.navdir = 'vertical';

This is the vertical display, if you want to display horizontally, just remove this line of code.